# network-manager connection on eth0 is active even when there is no cable plugged to it

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, networkmanager

I have a device with wifi and wired network. there is one nmcli connection for each network and connection on eth0 has priority over wlan0. the problem is that even there is no cable plugged to eth0 nmcli thinks its up and its connection become active so the real connection that uses wifi doesn't work properly. here are some info when network cable is unplugged and wifi is connected:

```
~$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate 
down
```

```
~$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: external
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Link detected: no
```

```
~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 76:14:a0:8d:39:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::7414:a0ff:fe8d:3951/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:93:7f:35:a3:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.61/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::1a93:7fff:fe35:a330/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

up to here everything says eth0 is down but from now there are wrong info

```
~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:14:a0:8d:39:51  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7414:a0ff:fe8d:3951/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:314 (314.0 B)
          Interrupt:114 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1344 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1344 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:166860 (166.8 KB)  TX bytes:166860 (166.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:93:7f:35:a3:30  
          inet addr:10.42.0.61  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1a93:7fff:fe35:a330/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21791 (21.7 KB)  TX bytes:19559 (19.5 KB)
```

```
~$ nmcli d show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         76:14:A0:8D:39:51
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     wired_con
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.100/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7414:a0ff:fe8d:3951/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         18:93:7F:35:A3:30
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     wave_admin
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.61/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.42.0.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.42.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::1a93:7fff:fe35:a330/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            16436
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

```
~$ nmcli connection show --active
NAME        UUID                                  TYPE             DEVICE 
wave_admin  5843d36e-ef73-4f06-8d02-561ed320f235  802-11-wireless  wlan0  
wired_con   50218355-86b8-4134-af28-5585c542e886  802-3-ethernet   eth0
```